# Filtering data in another worksheet using multiple non-contiguous cell values

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I've looked around for the past few days to find an answer to this, but haven't found anything that refers to all aspects of my query. I'm hoping that somebody here can help me/point me in the right direction!

Essentially, I have a Store List and a Customer list (with the store each customer has visited) in two different sheets within one workbook, comprising a one to many relationship. I want to be able to filter the Customer List dynamically by selecting stores in the Store List, although have only managed to filter by one value (Store) so far, using the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
Sheet2.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
Sheet2.Activate
End If
End Sub
```

Though this is, of course, only a solution for when one store needs to be selected. Should I need to make a non-contiguous selection of cells, how would I go around this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way to do it would be to handle multiple selections. The code looks like shown bellow (TblCustomer is your "Table1"):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim rgSel As Range, rgCell As Range
  Dim cellsFound As Integer
  Dim filters() As String

  Set rgSel = Selection
  cellsFound = 0

  For Each rgCell In rgSel

    If rgCell.Column = 1 Then
      cellsFound = cellsFound + 1
      ReDim Preserve filters(cellsFound)
      filters(cellsFound - 1) = rgCell
    End If

  Next rgCell

  If cellsFound > 0 Then
    Sheet2.ListObjects("TblCustomers").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filters, Operator:=xlFilterValues

   'you may need to select the customer sheet manually after you made your multiple selection,
   'otherwise you'll just jump to it avery time you change the selection
   'Sheet2.Activate

  End If

End Sub
```